# What is the difference between loadu and load?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

What is more efficient and why?

Specifically `_mm_loadu_si128` vs. `_mm_load_si128` in C.

(Editor's note: or this was tagged assembly, possibly they meant `movdqu` vs. `movdqa` in hand-written asm.  Which is *not* the same thing, especially without AVX, because `_mm_load_si128` can compile into a memory operand for an ALU instruction with no separate `movdqa` at all.)

Comment: Please tag with appropriate CPU (family).

Comment: Intel Xeon E5620, SSE

Comment: You may want to read the FAQ and [Question-HowTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Guess this can be expected from a Computer Science student ;) And of course welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: @phresnel i'm a newbie, thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`loadu` is used for misaligned loads (from addresses that are not aligned to a 16 byte multiple) and `load` is used for aligned loads. If you know that your source address is correctly aligned then `load` would normally be more efficient as it only needs one read cycle and doesn't have to deal with fixing up multiple chunks of misaligned data.  On older Intel CPUs the performance penalty for misaligned loads was quite significant (typically > 2x) but on more recent CPUs (e.g. Core i5/i7) the penalty is almost negligible. Note that using `loadu` for aligned data is OK apart from the aforementioned performance penalty, but using `load` with misaligned data will generate an exception (i.e. crash).

Comment: Or it could mean `load` vs `load unsigned` (as in MIPS: `LB`/`LH` vs `LBU`/`LHU`, where one pair does sign extension when loading a value from memory into a register while the other does zero extension in the process).

Comment: OP has now clarified - it's x86/SSE

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze It doesn't. OP isn't asking for guesswork here.

Comment: @EJP My comment was made before the clarification from the OP.

Comment: Can you (or do you know of any source that can) quantify how small the "negligible" penalty is? [This Intel article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/practical-intel-avx-optimization-on-2nd-generation-intel-core-processors) says there was a "degradation of more than 20% when working with misaligned data and using the `loadu` and `storeu` instructions" in some specific case.

Comment: @mrm: it really depends on the access pattern and how much computation you are performing relative to I/O. I've seen small throughput hits (10% or less) when using misaligned loads on Core i7, and my hunch is that these result from crossing cache line boundaries and other indirect penalties when data is not correctly aligned. Bottom line: use aligned loads/stores wherever possible, but misaligned loads/stores are not a huge problem when you are forced to use them.

Comment: `loadu` on aligned data can still cost front-end bandwidth, because the compiler can't fold unaligned loads into memory operands for ALU instructions, and has to use a separate `movdqu`.  In practice it's often fine, but more uops take more space in the out-of-order window even if you aren't bottlenecked on front-end throughput.  (And is less hyperthreading-friendly.)

Comment: (`loadu` on aligned data is only a problem without AVX; AVX allows memory source operands to be unaligned, so `loadu` can be "folded" into a `vaddps xmm0, [rdi]` or whatever.  But still beware of GCC tune settings that split unaligned stores and/or loads: [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726) - terrible if the data is *usually* aligned, unless you use `-mtune=haswell` or something (implied by `-march=haswell`))