# -march=haswell vs -march=core-avx2 vs -mavx2

Tags: gcc, x86, clang, compiler-optimization, avx2

Title says it all. What are the differences and tradeoffs between -march=haswell, -march=core-avx2, and -mavx2 for compiling avx2 intrinsics?

I know that -mavx2 is a flag and -march=haswell/core-avx2 are *architectures* which just translate to a bunch of flags. So -mavx2 is a subset of the other two. But beyond that, how do I choose the right one for my application?

In particular, if I'm compiling for Skylake and adding -mtune=skylake, but I can't actually do -march=skylake, how do I decide and why? (That's my particular case, but also interested in the more general tradeoffs).

Comment: `-march` sets -mtune, and enables other useful stuff you forgot like `-mfma` and `-mbmi` / `-mbmi2`.  `-march=haswell -mtune=skylake` could be useful if you want to enable a Haswell baseline for compatibility, but tune for Skylake.  (There's very little difference between tuning heuristics for those microarchitectures, and probably no new instructions that GCC would use automatically.  For SKL specifically, see [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646))

Comment: Thanks Peter! Where can I look up the difference in flags for `-march=haswell` vs `-march=core-avx2`?

Comment: I've never been clear on exactly what `-march=core-avx2` or `-march=core-i7` were supposed to be, whether it was a moving target as newer i7s came out, or whether it was just Haswell and Nehalem.  I suspect the latter.  So as far as I'm concerned, good riddance to those stupid names that are trying to be generic but actually aren't.  (See the section in [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362225) where I explained why "i7" isn't a useful name to describe any group of CPUs, since Nehalem is quite different from Sandybridge.)

Comment: [How to correctly determine -march and -mtune for Intel processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56870475) sheds some light on `core-avx2` being a synonym for `haswell`.

Comment: Thanks -- feel free to close this question if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-march` sets `-mtune`, and enables other useful stuff you forgot like `-mfma` and `-mbmi` / `-mbmi2` which aren't implied by `-mavx2`.

Unfortunately GCC's `-mtune=generic` doesn't adapt itself to the subset of CPUs that support the extensions enabled.  Most notably, `-mavx2` rules out Sandy Bridge, but doesn't imply `-mno-avx256-split-unaligned-load -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-store` ([Why doesn't gcc resolve _mm256_loadu_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626726/why-doesnt-gcc-resolve-mm256-loadu-pd-as-single-vmovupd)).  Out of all AVX2 CPUs, only I think Excavator would really benefit much from those options, and it's not a big fraction of market share, and I think misaligned 32-byte load/store isn't disastrous on it like it was on Sandybridge.  GCC11 and later have a tune=generic that does do unaligned 32-byte load/store (https://godbolt.org/z/qr9cEcne3) so this specific issue is no longer critical if you only care about AVX2 and newer CPUs.  But still you generally want a `-mtune=` option somewhat appropriate for the set of CPUs you're targeting.  But usually erring on the side of less loop unrolling, since too much can hurt I-cache / uop cache hit rate.

**AVX2 CPUs have been widespread for long enough that `-mtune=generic` happens to be mostly appropriate for them in GCC11 and later, fortunately.** (Especially CPUs like Haswell and Zen2 that have 32-byte-wide load/store units). But in general, with other CPU features and other far-future cases, that won't always be true.
But still don't just use `-mavx2`, that will leave out `-mfma` (which all AVX2 CPUs support except for one Via model), and leave out `-mbmi`/2 which I think all AVX2 CPUs also support.  More efficient variable-count shifts are always nice, and so is lzcnt/tzcnt and efficient `x &= x-1` lowest-set-bit idioms.

---

`-march=haswell -mtune=skylake` could be useful if you want to enable a Haswell baseline for compatibility, but tune for Skylake. (There's very little difference between tuning heuristics for those microarchitectures, and probably no new instructions that GCC would use automatically. For SKL specifically, see also [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646) which isn't implied by `-march=skylake`)

---

#### `-march=core-avx2` and similar are an obsolete naming convention

It's just a synonym for `-march=haswell`, AFAIK.  But maybe leaving `-mtune=generic`, unlike `-march=haswell` which sets `-mtune=haswell`.  [How to correctly determine -march and -mtune for Intel processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870475/how-to-correctly-determine-march-and-mtune-for-intel-processors) has more details.

`-march=core-i7` is I think just a synonym for Nehalem, which is really dumb because Nehalem (1st-gen i7) is a different microarchitecture from Sandy Bridge and later (2nd-gen i7).  Intel unfortunately kept that branding through [SnB's major re-architecting of the internals](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/), although the 3-level cache with shared inclusive L3 has been a constant.

There's no such thing as "a generic i7", because i7 includes two different microarchitectures, one with a uop cache, one without.

**Good riddance to those stupid ambiguous confusing `-march=` / `-mtune` names that are trying to be generic but actually aren't.**

---

It would be *nice* if there was a `-march=generic-avx2` to tune for Haswell and later, Zen1 and later, etc., using the common subset of instructions they all support efficiently.  And setting tuning options appropriate for all of them, not going too crazy unrolling.  But there isn't.

Or more generally, `-mtune=generic-enabled` or something that would look at the enabled `-m` options and not care about CPUs that couldn't run this code.  e.g. not doing `rep ret` if you enabled any features that a Phenom II couldn't run, such as AVX.  **[GCC bug 78762](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78762) is basically a feature request for that.**

(Current GCC `-mtune=generic` no longer uses `rep ret`; Phenom II is old enough that GCC doesn't spend extra code-size to avoid potholes there.  Most binary releases of software built with GCC use a GCC version that was in development a year or more before that, so there's some lead time in terms of what's appropriate for `-mtune=generic`.  The CPU with a glass jaw / performance pothole you're working around doesn't have to be totally gone before a current nightly build of GCC stops tuning for it.)