# The same AVX instruction set code has a huge performance gap between Intel Core and AMD Ryzen

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86, intrinsics

I want to use the AVX instruction set to accelerate the convolution operation from 8-channel image to 8-channel image. I use a 3x3 convolution kernel. My code is as follows:

```
        const float* kptr = kernels;
        const float* bptr = biases;

        __m256 _out0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(bptr);
        __m256 _out1 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
        __m256 _out2 = _mm256_setzero_ps();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
        {
            const __m256 _r00 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(tl + i);
            const __m256 _r01 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(tc + i);
            const __m256 _r02 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(tr + i);
            const __m256 _r03 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(ml + i);
            const __m256 _r04 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(mc + i);
            const __m256 _r05 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(mr + i);
            const __m256 _r06 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(bl + i);
            const __m256 _r07 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(bc + i);
            const __m256 _r08 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(br + i);

            const __m256 _k00 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72);
            const __m256 _k01 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 8);
            const __m256 _k02 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 16);
            const __m256 _k03 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 24);
            const __m256 _k04 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 32);
            const __m256 _k05 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 40);
            const __m256 _k06 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 48);
            const __m256 _k07 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 56);
            const __m256 _k08 = _mm256_loadu_ps(kptr + i * 72 + 64);

            _out0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r00, _k00, _out0);
            _out1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r01, _k01, _out1);
            _out2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r02, _k02, _out2);
            _out0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r03, _k03, _out0);
            _out1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r04, _k04, _out1);
            _out2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r05, _k05, _out2);
            _out0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r06, _k06, _out0);
            _out1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r07, _k07, _out1);
            _out2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_r08, _k08, _out2);
        }
        _out0 = _mm256_max_ps(_mm256_add_ps(_out0, _mm256_add_ps(_out1, _out2)), _mm256_setzero_ps());

        _mm256_storeu_ps(outMat, _out0);
```

On Ryzen, this is very effective. Tested on R5 2600 and R5 3500U, I can get 2-4 times performance improvement compared to ordinary C++ code with compiler optimization . But on Intel Core CPU, It is even 50% slower than ordinary C++ code with compiler optimization , tested on i7 8750H and i3 4170, both of them. Actually, 3500U is 4 times faster than i7 8750H in this case.

I am confused about this. I found that the most time-consuming instruction in Intel CPU is the fmadd instruction, but it still have no improvement after replacing fmadd with the equivalent avx instruction.

I also considered the limitation of the number of registers, but after trying to reduce the number of __mm256 variables, the situation may get worse.

The compiler and parameters are the same, I compiled with msvc2019, and I even used the same binary.

The memory layout of weights(`kptr`) is CHWB, input image pixels(`tl` to `br`) is BHWC.

During the test, I noticed that in the same scenario, i7 8750h is full load, while the 2600 is about 35%, and the performance is 8 times that of the former.

Any suggestions?

I didn't find a good way to disassemble the binary compiled by MSVC, so I compiled it under Linux and disassembled it with GDB. Here's what I got using GDB disassembly:

`-g -fopenmp -lpthread -mavx2 -mfma -O3`

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
898       return *(__m256_u *)__P;
   0x00007fffff710967 <+135>:   vxorps %xmm1,%xmm1,%xmm1
   0x00007fffff71096b <+139>:   lea    0x4(,%r13,4),%r13
   0x00007fffff710973 <+147>:   lea    0x4(,%rdi,4),%rdi
   0x00007fffff71097b <+155>:   vmovaps %ymm1,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff71097f <+159>:   mov    (%rax),%r10
   0x00007fffff710982 <+162>:   mov    0x10(%r9),%rax
   0x00007fffff710986 <+166>:   lea    0x4(,%rsi,4),%rsi
   0x00007fffff71098e <+174>:   lea    (%r11,%rdi,1),%rbx
   0x00007fffff710992 <+178>:   lea    (%r11,%rsi,1),%r12
   0x00007fffff710996 <+182>:   lea    (%rdx,%rsi,1),%r9
   0x00007fffff71099a <+186>:   add    %r13,%r11
   0x00007fffff71099d <+189>:   add    %rcx,%rsi
   0x00007fffff7109a0 <+192>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x00007fffff7109a3 <+195>:   vmovups (%r10),%xmm7
   0x00007fffff7109a8 <+200>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r10),%ymm7,%ymm0

/home/tianzer/Anime4KCPP/Anime4KCore/src/CPUCNNProcessor.cpp:
390             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
=> 0x00007fffff7109af <+207>:   lea    (%rdx,%rdi,1),%r10
   0x00007fffff7109b3 <+211>:   add    %r13,%rdx
   0x00007fffff7109b6 <+214>:   add    %rcx,%rdi
   0x00007fffff7109b9 <+217>:   add    %r13,%rcx
   0x00007fffff7109bc <+220>:   lea    0x900(%rax),%r13

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
735       return (__m256) __builtin_ia32_vbroadcastss256 (__X);
   0x00007fffff7109c3 <+227>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rbx),%ymm11
   0x00007fffff7109c9 <+233>:   vmovups (%rax),%xmm5
   0x00007fffff7109cd <+237>:   add    $0x8,%rbx
   0x00007fffff7109d1 <+241>:   add    $0x240,%rax
   0x00007fffff7109d7 <+247>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%r11),%ymm6
   0x00007fffff7109dd <+253>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%r9),%ymm8
   0x00007fffff7109e3 <+259>:   add    $0x8,%r12
   0x00007fffff7109e7 <+263>:   add    $0x8,%r11
   0x00007fffff7109eb <+267>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rdx),%ymm7
   0x00007fffff7109f1 <+273>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rsi),%ymm4
   0x00007fffff7109f7 <+279>:   add    $0x8,%r10
   0x00007fffff7109fb <+283>:   add    $0x8,%r9
   0x00007fffff7109ff <+287>:   vbroadcastss -0xc(%r12),%ymm10
   0x00007fffff710a06 <+294>:   vbroadcastss -0xc(%r10),%ymm9
   0x00007fffff710a0c <+300>:   add    $0x8,%rdx
   0x00007fffff710a10 <+304>:   add    $0x8,%rdi
   0x00007fffff710a14 <+308>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rcx),%ymm2
   0x00007fffff710a1a <+314>:   vbroadcastss -0xc(%rdi),%ymm12

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/fmaintrin.h:
65        return (__m256)__builtin_ia32_vfmaddps256 ((__v8sf)__A, (__v8sf)__B,
   0x00007fffff710a20 <+320>:   add    $0x8,%rsi
   0x00007fffff710a24 <+324>:   add    $0x8,%rcx
   0x00007fffff710a28 <+328>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x230(%rax),%ymm5,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710a32 <+338>:   vfmadd231ps %ymm5,%ymm11,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710a37 <+343>:   vmovups -0x220(%rax),%xmm5
   0x00007fffff710a3f <+351>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x210(%rax),%ymm5,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710a49 <+361>:   vfmadd231ps %ymm5,%ymm10,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710a4e <+366>:   vmovups -0x200(%rax),%xmm5
   0x00007fffff710a56 <+374>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x1f0(%rax),%ymm5,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710a60 <+384>:   vfmadd231ps %ymm5,%ymm6,%ymm1
   0x00007fffff710a65 <+389>:   vmovups -0x1e0(%rax),%xmm6
   0x00007fffff710a6d <+397>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x1d0(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm11
   0x00007fffff710a77 <+407>:   vmovups -0x1c0(%rax),%xmm6
   0x00007fffff710a7f <+415>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x1b0(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm10
   0x00007fffff710a89 <+425>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm11,%ymm0,%ymm9
   0x00007fffff710a8e <+430>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm10,%ymm3,%ymm8
   0x00007fffff710a93 <+435>:   vmovups -0x1a0(%rax),%xmm3
   0x00007fffff710a9b <+443>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x190(%rax),%ymm3,%ymm6
   0x00007fffff710aa5 <+453>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm6,%ymm1,%ymm7
   0x00007fffff710aaa <+458>:   vmovups -0x180(%rax),%xmm1
   0x00007fffff710ab2 <+466>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x170(%rax),%ymm1,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710abc <+476>:   vmovups -0x160(%rax),%xmm1
   0x00007fffff710ac4 <+484>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x150(%rax),%ymm1,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710ace <+494>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm5,%ymm9,%ymm12
   0x00007fffff710ad3 <+499>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r11),%ymm1
   0x00007fffff710ad9 <+505>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r10),%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710adf <+511>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm3,%ymm8,%ymm4
   0x00007fffff710ae4 <+516>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r12),%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710aeb <+523>:   vmovaps %ymm12,%ymm11
   0x00007fffff710af0 <+528>:   vmovaps %ymm4,%ymm10
   0x00007fffff710af4 <+532>:   vmovups -0x140(%rax),%xmm4
   0x00007fffff710afc <+540>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x130(%rax),%ymm4,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710b06 <+550>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r9),%ymm4
   0x00007fffff710b0c <+556>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm0,%ymm7,%ymm2
   0x00007fffff710b11 <+561>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rbx),%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710b17 <+567>:   vmovaps %ymm2,%ymm6

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
735       return (__m256) __builtin_ia32_vbroadcastss256 (__X);
   0x00007fffff710b1b <+571>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rdx),%ymm2
   0x00007fffff710b21 <+577>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rsi),%ymm8
   0x00007fffff710b27 <+583>:   vmovups -0x120(%rax),%xmm13
   0x00007fffff710b2f <+591>:   vmovups -0x100(%rax),%xmm14
   0x00007fffff710b37 <+599>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x110(%rax),%ymm13,%ymm12
   0x00007fffff710b41 <+609>:   vmovups -0xe0(%rax),%xmm15
   0x00007fffff710b49 <+617>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rdi),%ymm9
   0x00007fffff710b4f <+623>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rcx),%ymm7

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/fmaintrin.h:
65        return (__m256)__builtin_ia32_vfmaddps256 ((__v8sf)__A, (__v8sf)__B,
   0x00007fffff710b55 <+629>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm12,%ymm11,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710b5a <+634>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0xf0(%rax),%ymm14,%ymm11
   0x00007fffff710b64 <+644>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm11,%ymm10,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710b69 <+649>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0xd0(%rax),%ymm15,%ymm10
   0x00007fffff710b73 <+659>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm10,%ymm6,%ymm1
   0x00007fffff710b78 <+664>:   vmovups -0xc0(%rax),%xmm6
   0x00007fffff710b80 <+672>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0xb0(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm6
   0x00007fffff710b8a <+682>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm6,%ymm0,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff710b8f <+687>:   vmovups -0xa0(%rax),%xmm6
   0x00007fffff710b97 <+695>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x90(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710ba1 <+705>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm0,%ymm3,%ymm4
   0x00007fffff710ba6 <+710>:   vmovups -0x80(%rax),%xmm3
   0x00007fffff710bab <+715>:   vmovaps %ymm9,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710baf <+719>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x70(%rax),%ymm3,%ymm6
   0x00007fffff710bb6 <+726>:   vmovups -0x40(%rax),%xmm3
   0x00007fffff710bbb <+731>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x30(%rax),%ymm3,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710bc2 <+738>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm6,%ymm1,%ymm2
   0x00007fffff710bc7 <+743>:   vmovups -0x60(%rax),%xmm1
   0x00007fffff710bcc <+748>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x50(%rax),%ymm1,%ymm6
   0x00007fffff710bd3 <+755>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm6,%ymm5,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710bd8 <+760>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm8,%ymm4,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff710bdd <+765>:   vmovups -0x20(%rax),%xmm4
   0x00007fffff710be2 <+770>:   vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x10(%rax),%ymm4,%ymm1
   0x00007fffff710be9 <+777>:   vfmadd132ps %ymm7,%ymm2,%ymm1

/home/tianzer/Anime4KCPP/Anime4KCore/src/CPUCNNProcessor.cpp:
390             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
   0x00007fffff710bee <+782>:   cmp    %rax,%r13
   0x00007fffff710bf1 <+785>:   jne    0x7fffff7109c3 <std::_Function_handler<void(int, int, float*, float*), Anime4KCPP::CPU::CNNProcessor::conv8To8(const FP*, const FP*, cv::Mat&)::<lambda(int, int, Anime4KCPP::CPU::ChanFP, Anime4KCPP::CPU::LineFP)> >::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data &, int &&, int &&, float *&&, float *&&)+227>

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
1230      return __extension__ (__m256){ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
   0x00007fffff710bf7 <+791>:   vaddps %ymm3,%ymm0,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710bfb <+795>:   vaddps %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff710bff <+799>:   vxorps %xmm1,%xmm1,%xmm1
   0x00007fffff710c03 <+803>:   vmaxps %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0

904       *(__m256_u *)__P = __A;
   0x00007fffff710c07 <+807>:   vmovups %xmm0,(%r8)
   0x00007fffff710c0c <+812>:   vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm0,0x10(%r8)
   0x00007fffff710c13 <+819>:   vzeroupper
   0x00007fffff710c16 <+822>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00007fffff710c17 <+823>:   pop    %r12
   0x00007fffff710c19 <+825>:   pop    %r13
   0x00007fffff710c1b <+827>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00007fffff710c1c <+828>:   retq
```

if I use -march=native to build:
`-g -fopenmp -lpthread -march=native -O3`

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
898       return *(__m256_u *)__P;
   0x00007fffff711596 <+134>:   vxorps %xmm1,%xmm1,%xmm1
   0x00007fffff71159a <+138>:   lea    0x4(,%r10,4),%r13
   0x00007fffff7115a2 <+146>:   lea    0x4(,%rdi,4),%rdi
   0x00007fffff7115aa <+154>:   vmovaps %ymm1,%ymm2
   0x00007fffff7115ae <+158>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x00007fffff7115b1 <+161>:   lea    0x4(,%rsi,4),%rsi
   0x00007fffff7115b9 <+169>:   lea    (%r11,%rdi,1),%rbx
   0x00007fffff7115bd <+173>:   lea    (%r11,%rsi,1),%r12
   0x00007fffff7115c1 <+177>:   lea    (%rdx,%rdi,1),%r10
   0x00007fffff7115c5 <+181>:   add    %r13,%r11
   0x00007fffff7115c8 <+184>:   add    %rcx,%rdi
   0x00007fffff7115cb <+187>:   vmovups (%rax),%ymm0

/home/tianzer/Anime4KCPP/Anime4KCore/src/CPUCNNProcessor.cpp:
390             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
=> 0x00007fffff7115cf <+191>:   mov    0x10(%r9),%rax
   0x00007fffff7115d3 <+195>:   lea    (%rdx,%rsi,1),%r9
   0x00007fffff7115d7 <+199>:   add    %r13,%rdx
   0x00007fffff7115da <+202>:   add    %rcx,%rsi
   0x00007fffff7115dd <+205>:   add    %r13,%rcx
   0x00007fffff7115e0 <+208>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x00007fffff7115e3 <+211>:   lea    0x900(%rax),%r13

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
735       return (__m256) __builtin_ia32_vbroadcastss256 (__X);
   0x00007fffff7115ea <+218>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%r11),%ymm4
   0x00007fffff7115f0 <+224>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rbx),%ymm3
   0x00007fffff7115f6 <+230>:   add    $0x8,%r12
   0x00007fffff7115fa <+234>:   add    $0x240,%rax
   0x00007fffff711600 <+240>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%r10),%ymm11
   0x00007fffff711606 <+246>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%r9),%ymm10
   0x00007fffff71160c <+252>:   add    $0x8,%rbx
   0x00007fffff711610 <+256>:   add    $0x8,%r11
   0x00007fffff711614 <+260>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rdx),%ymm9
   0x00007fffff71161a <+266>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rdi),%ymm8
   0x00007fffff711620 <+272>:   add    $0x8,%r10
   0x00007fffff711624 <+276>:   add    $0x8,%r9
   0x00007fffff711628 <+280>:   vbroadcastss -0xc(%r12),%ymm5
   0x00007fffff71162f <+287>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rsi),%ymm7
   0x00007fffff711635 <+293>:   add    $0x8,%rdx
   0x00007fffff711639 <+297>:   add    $0x8,%rdi
   0x00007fffff71163d <+301>:   vbroadcastss -0x4(%rcx),%ymm6

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/fmaintrin.h:
65        return (__m256)__builtin_ia32_vfmaddps256 ((__v8sf)__A, (__v8sf)__B,
   0x00007fffff711643 <+307>:   add    $0x8,%rsi
   0x00007fffff711647 <+311>:   add    $0x8,%rcx
   0x00007fffff71164b <+315>:   vfmadd132ps -0x240(%rax),%ymm0,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff711654 <+324>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r10),%ymm0
   0x00007fffff71165a <+330>:   vfmadd132ps -0x220(%rax),%ymm2,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff711663 <+339>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rsi),%ymm2
   0x00007fffff711669 <+345>:   vfmadd231ps -0x200(%rax),%ymm4,%ymm1
   0x00007fffff711672 <+354>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rdx),%ymm4
   0x00007fffff711678 <+360>:   vfmadd132ps -0x1e0(%rax),%ymm3,%ymm11
   0x00007fffff711681 <+369>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rcx),%ymm3
   0x00007fffff711687 <+375>:   vfmadd132ps -0x1c0(%rax),%ymm5,%ymm10
   0x00007fffff711690 <+384>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r9),%ymm5
   0x00007fffff711696 <+390>:   vfmadd132ps -0x1a0(%rax),%ymm1,%ymm9
   0x00007fffff71169f <+399>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rdi),%ymm1
   0x00007fffff7116a5 <+405>:   vfmadd231ps -0x180(%rax),%ymm8,%ymm11
   0x00007fffff7116ae <+414>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%rbx),%ymm8
   0x00007fffff7116b4 <+420>:   vfmadd231ps -0x160(%rax),%ymm7,%ymm10
   0x00007fffff7116bd <+429>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r12),%ymm7
   0x00007fffff7116c4 <+436>:   vfmadd231ps -0x140(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm9

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
735       return (__m256) __builtin_ia32_vbroadcastss256 (__X);
   0x00007fffff7116cd <+445>:   vbroadcastss -0x8(%r11),%ymm6

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/fmaintrin.h:
65        return (__m256)__builtin_ia32_vfmaddps256 ((__v8sf)__A, (__v8sf)__B,
   0x00007fffff7116d3 <+451>:   vfmadd132ps -0x120(%rax),%ymm11,%ymm8
   0x00007fffff7116dc <+460>:   vfmadd132ps -0x100(%rax),%ymm10,%ymm7
   0x00007fffff7116e5 <+469>:   vfmadd132ps -0xe0(%rax),%ymm9,%ymm6
   0x00007fffff7116ee <+478>:   vfmadd132ps -0xc0(%rax),%ymm8,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff7116f7 <+487>:   vfmadd132ps -0xa0(%rax),%ymm7,%ymm5
   0x00007fffff711700 <+496>:   vfmadd132ps -0x80(%rax),%ymm6,%ymm4
   0x00007fffff711706 <+502>:   vfmadd132ps -0x20(%rax),%ymm4,%ymm3
   0x00007fffff71170c <+508>:   vfmadd231ps -0x60(%rax),%ymm1,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff711712 <+514>:   vfmadd132ps -0x40(%rax),%ymm5,%ymm2
   0x00007fffff711718 <+520>:   vmovaps %ymm3,%ymm1

/home/tianzer/Anime4KCPP/Anime4KCore/src/CPUCNNProcessor.cpp:
390             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
   0x00007fffff71171c <+524>:   cmp    %rax,%r13
   0x00007fffff71171f <+527>:   jne    0x7fffff7115ea <std::_Function_handler<void(int, int, float*, float*), Anime4KCPP::CPU::CNNProcessor::conv8To8(const FP*, const FP*, cv::Mat&)::<lambda(int, int, Anime4KCPP::CPU::ChanFP, Anime4KCPP::CPU::LineFP)> >::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data &, int &&, int &&, float *&&, float *&&)+218>

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:
1230      return __extension__ (__m256){ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
   0x00007fffff711725 <+533>:   vaddps %ymm2,%ymm0,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff711729 <+537>:   vxorps %xmm1,%xmm1,%xmm1
   0x00007fffff71172d <+541>:   vaddps %ymm3,%ymm0,%ymm0
   0x00007fffff711731 <+545>:   vmaxps %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0

904       *(__m256_u *)__P = __A;
   0x00007fffff711735 <+549>:   vmovups %ymm0,(%r8)
   0x00007fffff71173a <+554>:   vzeroupper
   0x00007fffff71173d <+557>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00007fffff71173e <+558>:   pop    %r12
   0x00007fffff711740 <+560>:   pop    %r13
   0x00007fffff711742 <+562>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00007fffff711743 <+563>:   retq
```

Benchmark results from Intel i3 4170, the score is the reciprocal of the processing time multiplied by a factor, use the bin from gcc, which is consistent with the disassembly above. results of MSVC are almost the same:

```
ordinary C++ code: 4.13368
-mavx2 -mfma: 2.51132
-march=native: 2.46779
```

I noticed that under `-march=native` compilation, vfmadd231ps fetches operands directly from memory. Is it because Intel's L2 is not big enough? Ryzen's L2 per core is twice that of Intel.

Comment: have you done any kind of profiling?

Comment: @user253751 I tried to find out the performance bottleneck of Intel CPU by deleting line by line. In addition, I tried to change the order of instructions or introduce some temporary variables. Although it has been improved to some extent, it is still slower than C++ code.

Comment: Did you use the same compiler on all machines?  Like `gcc -march=native -O3`?  Was the scalar C++ code maybe already auto-vectorizing, maybe with `-ffast-math`, on the Intel CPUs?  What exact asm ran slowly on your Haswell and Skylake CPUs?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code so we can *reproduce* your problem? Possibly the ordinary C++ code too.

Comment: I'd group these differently, so that the 0/1/2 values are loaded and added, then the 3/4/5 elements, then the 6/7/8 ones. This might reduce register pressure.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes Of course, the compiler and parameters are the same, I compiled with msvc2019, and I even used the same binary

Comment: Ok, then say that in your question instead of leaving everyone wondering.

Comment: @ Jérôme Richard The complete code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/TianZerL/Anime4KCPP/blob/0c9058834f7513648fb7d19187a9adbc46b052f1/Anime4KCore/src/CPUCNNProcessor.cpp#L360).  Note that the memory layout of weights in normal C + + code is different from AVX version.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: You mention that fewer variables was worse, is more variables better? 3 parallel FMAs is not a lot.. though, it also isn't a lot on Zen so that doesn't really explain the gap

Comment: @harold : After testing, 3 is a more appropriate number, increase will not have obvious benefits, and may even reduce performance, for both Intel and AMD.

Comment: Is kernels aligned to 32 or 64 byte?

Comment: @ Surt : Align to 32 bytes with compiler instructions

Comment: What is the size of the tested images? The actual number of channel? Does the problem appear on small images (eg. smaller than 400x300)?

Comment: @ Jérôme Richard : I tested on 256x256 and 1920x1080, 8 channel, both of them.

Comment: @TianZerL: don't leave a space after the `@` - that will stop SO from notifying people when you reply.

Comment: You said earlier you were using MSVC, and the same binary everywhere.  Now you're showing disassembly of GCC output where you apparently forgot to use `-march=native` to set tuning options as well as arch options.  (note the split loads involving `vinsertf128` to implement `_mm256_loadu_ps`).  See [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726).  I would have mentioned that sooner if you hadn't claimed to be using only MSVC; that was my first guess from seeing the source code.

Comment: Both your  Ryzen CPUs are Zen1 / Zen+ microarchitectures where all 256-bit operations are split into 128-bit halves, so `vmovaps ymm` costs about the same as `vmovups xmm` + `vinsertf128`.  So they're not feeling the cost of GCC wasting so many instructions for the Intel CPUs.  I also have to wonder if you're actually comparing MSVC against GCC executables, since you also say you used MSVC.

Comment: Your update shows disassembly for `gcc -O3 -march=native` but you haven't shown benchmarks for that build.  If this is just some random build separate from what you actually benchmarked, that's useless.  I could have seen how it compiled with GCC myself, on https://godbolt.org/.  The point of that request for disassembly was to see what exact machine code *you* were benchmarking.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I didn't find a good way to disassemble the binary compiled by MSVC, so I compiled it under Linux and disassembled it with GDB. I have noticed the problem of `vinsertf128` and tried to use `-march=native` to avoid it, but the result didn't change, so I don't think that's the problem. I've added the result with  `-march=native` disassembly to the question.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: The performance of bin from MSVC and GCC is almost the same, Intel is slower than ordinary C + + code.

Comment: Ok, then put those details in the question, along with actual hard numbers.  Knowing what *absolute* performance we're trying to explain can help rule out or confirm some possible bottlenecks.  (e.g. 2x 128-bit FMA per clock on the Zen1 CPUs.)

Comment: *vfmadd231ps fetches operands directly from memory.* - all loads are cacheable.  Folding a memory operand into `vfmadd231ps` just saves front-end uop bandwidth vs. doing it with a separate `vmovaps (mem), %ymm`.  Compare with the `vmovups` / `vinsertf128` loads in the other version, and see [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726) (which I also linked earlier) for the explanation of that difference.  So apparently that's much of a bottleneck for your Haswell CPU.

Comment: You haven't shown what problem-size you're testing, or anything that would indicate any absolute performance in terms of GB/s load bandwidth or FMAs per clock cycle, still just some relative performance numbers.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I see, but how should I test GB / s load bandwidth or FMAS per clock cycle? Is there anything for reference?

Comment: Post something that makes it possible to figure out how many times the inner loop ran, like your benchmark framework with a repeat count, and *absolute* time in seconds, not some scaled "score".  Then we can calculate anything that needs calculating, and people can test it on their own machines with whatever perf counters they want.  (Assuming you post a [mcve] benchmark that can be compiled as-is and reproduces the effect.)

Answer (score 1):

If I read the code correctly, the first calculation of `out0` requires just `_r00` and `_k00`, then `out1` requires `_r01` and `_k01`, etcetera. Then, for `out0` you need `_r03` and `_k03`, etcetera.

That's recognizable code. A GRU neural network, I suppose?

Anyway, the trick is to merge the 9 sub-matrices in memory so that you only have one weights matrix, and then produce only one output vector. If you **really** need the output split into 3 vectors, you could copy the values in a later step, but that probably isn't necessary. And even if the copy is necessary, it's fairly cheap if you can merge it with the activation function.

Comment: The chief problem with the 9 inputs `tl` to `br` in addition to the 10th input `kptr` is that it breaks the cache pre-fetcher.

Comment: I use three _out is for better CPU pipeline optimization.

Comment: @TianZerL: CPU pipeline? I fear that your code will be limited by the bandwidth of the memory subsystem. As you noted, register pressure does not appear to be an issue.