# How to detect AVX2 support using gcc

Tags: gcc, g++, avx, instruction-set, avx2

I need to detect AVX2 support in my code take decisions accordingly. 
I am aware of two methods - `__builtin_cpu_supports("avx2")` and `#if defined(__AVX2__)`. Now the issue is one returns true and another false.
The test code is as follows -

```
int main(){
    if(__builtin_cpu_supports("avx2")){
        std::cout<< "Builtin methods supports" << std::endl;
    }
    
    
#if defined(__AVX2__)
    std::cout<<"Builtin symbol present"<<std::endl;
#endif
return 0;
}
```

And the output is as follows -

```
Builtin methods supports
```

I am running a i7 - 9750h. And my processor does support `AVX2` instruction set.

What is the correct way to identify. My GCC version in 9.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got this wrong. You can use the macro to check, at compile-time, if you've configured `gcc` to compile with AVX2 support. The builtin can check, at run-time, if the CPU it's currently running on supports the AVX2 extensions.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AtharvaDubey: "configured gcc..." means specifically `gcc -march=native`, `gcc -march=skylake`, or `-mavx2` (but don't *just* do the latter, it leaves out `-mfma`, `-mbmi2`, and especially leaves out tuning options to fix [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726))