# copy array of "vectors": by memcpy or iterate each?

Tags: c++, vector, simd, memcpy

here's a snippet of code I have:

```
for (int oscIndex = 0; oscIndex < kNumOscs; oscIndex++) {
    for (int voiceIndex = 0; voiceIndex < numVoices; voiceIndex += 4) {
        const int v = voiceIndex / 4;

        // vol
        osc[oscIndex][v] = _mm_mul_ps(osc[oscIndex][v], vol[oscIndex][v]);

        // prev output
        mPrevOutput[oscIndex][v] = osc[oscIndex][v];

        // out
        osc[oscIndex][v] = _mm_mul_ps(osc[oscIndex][v], out[oscIndex][v]);
    }
}
```

is it correct to copy values on `mPrevOutput` in this way?
or a (unique) `memcpy` will result faster?

`mPrevOutput` and `osc` have the same length (in this case, kNumOscs=4 x numVoices=16 x m128).

I'm on a windows/64 bit machine, using `FLAGS += -O3 -march=nocona -funsafe-math-optimizations`

That's how they are defined:

```
alignas(16) std::array<std::array<m128, 4>, kNumOscs> mPrevOutput; // member of a class
m128 osc[4][4]; // declared every time the function's class is executed
```

Comment: What's the declaration of `osc` and `mPrevOutput`?

Comment: @SebastianRedl added the details.

Comment: So generally speaking, the answer to the question "is X faster than Y" is *always* "write both and use a profiler to find out".

Comment: You're tuning for 64-bit Pentium 4?  (`-march=nocona` implies `-mtune=nocona`).  If you want nocona as a feature baseline, you could use `-march=nocona  -mtune=haswell`, or even `-mtune=generic` since arch=nocona doesn't exclude any old CPUs that tune=generic cares about.  (e.g. `-march=haswell -mtune=generic` would be [a less-good choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626726/why-doesnt-gcc-resolve-mm256-loadu-pd-as-single-vmovupd) because generic tuning options care about a lot of CPUs that don't have AVX2 / BMI2, )

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter. m128 types should use SSE operations, so assignment is fast. `memcpy` should be implemented as intrinsic, so should do the same.

But it all is up to the compiler and compilation options. Profile, inspect disassembly.