# bad_function_call thrown and segmentation fault caused when passing avx variables to std::function

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, vectorization, avx

This problem is found when writing some code related to computer graphics, a simplified version of the code is shown below:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define __AVX__ 1
#define __AVX2__ 1
#pragma GCC target("avx,avx2,popcnt,tune=native")
#include <immintrin.h>

namespace with_avx {
class vec {
   public:
    vec(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0, double t = 0) {
        vec_data = _mm256_set_pd(t, z, y, x);
    }
    __m256d vec_data;
};
}  // namespace with_avx

namespace without_avx {
class vec {
   public:
    vec(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0, double t = 0) {
        vec_data[0] = x, vec_data[1] = y, vec_data[2] = z, vec_data[3] = t;
    }
    double vec_data[4];
};
}  // namespace without_avx

#ifdef USE_AVX
using namespace with_avx;
#else
using namespace without_avx;
#endif

vec same(vec x) { return x; }
std::function<vec(vec)> stdfunc = same;

int main() { 
    vec rand_vec(rand(), rand(), rand());
    vec ret = stdfunc(rand_vec);
    std::cout<<(double)ret.vec_data[0];
}
```

If I compile the code with the flag `USE_AVX` like the following:

```
 g++-12 stdfunction_test.cpp -o ../build/unit_test -D USE_AVX -g
```

g++ will output some warnings:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/functional:59,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/stdc++.h:71,
                 from stdfunction_test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_function.h: In member function ‘_Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = with_avx::vec; _ArgTypes = {with_avx::vec}]’:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_function.h:587:7: note: the ABI for passing parameters with 32-byte alignment has changed in GCC 4.6
  587 |       operator()(_ArgTypes... __args) const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
```

Then if I run the code, sometimes segmentation fault is caused with the following output:

```
[1]    12710 segmentation fault  ../build/unit_test
```

Sometimes, bad_function_call is thrown with the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
[1]    12678 IOT instruction  ../build/unit_test
```

Both of these two errors are made when this line is executed:

```cpp
vec ret = stdfunc(rand_vec);
```

I then used gdb for backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7e35521 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e2c6f4 in std::__throw_bad_function_call() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000055555555558b in std::function<with_avx::vec (with_avx::vec)>::operator()(with_avx::vec) const (this=0x7fffffffda74,
    __args#0=...) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_function.h:590
#3  0x000055555555528d in main () at stdfunction_test.cpp:39
```

However if I don't add the flag, the code would run normally.

I think this is possibly caused by some kind of alignment problems like the warning sait I just don't know how to solve this.

My environment is listed on the following, hope they will be useful:

- g++ version: `g++-12 (Ubuntu 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) 12.0.1 20220319 (experimental) [master r12-7719-g8ca61ad148f]`
- OS: Ubuntu-22.04 running on WSL2

Comment: Not the reason for your problem, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the target architecture half way through the file is causing your issue. Presumably parts of `std::function`'s implementation changes with the target architecture. Moving your pragma to the start of the file fixes the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/WP5ah38WP

It'll be safer in general if you set your architecture target via the compiler command line (e.g. `-mavx2`) which will ensure all your code is compiled with the same architectures: https://godbolt.org/z/z5j79c5eh
Or better, use `-march=haswell` or `-march=native` to also set tuning options and enabled related ISA features like BMI1/2, because of things like [Why doesn't gcc resolve _mm256_loadu_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626726/why-doesnt-gcc-resolve-mm256-loadu-pd-as-single-vmovupd)

---

The calling convention for passing a `double __attribute__((vector_size(32)))` (such as `__m256d`) changes when AVX is available.

As you can see [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGz%2BpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZmakAA6oCoRODB7evgFBaRmOAmER0SxxCUm2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BgTV1WY3NBKVRsfGJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHMgGCgoA1ABumMh7JgDsVhoAgnu3e%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%2BL5aMZJCUKZd5PiYdkYTOSE%2BQFSkuRY1QZ2QZTFXJN4G1UD9mO0ulaNhCkkWpXZlLpMV2IlLTG0OVlZOkm47iU/SeWxW5t1M/Zwj2ABNABZfyNCVByFKFAlzNFBlrLU7TDmlWVhT0xsDIsDz/WFL89h8gKgpCoFritMxgVcHUOGWWhOG%2BXg/A4LRSFQTg3Gsaw9gUVZ1kArUeFIAhNHK5ZgxANcPW%2BJIAA4AE5gTOM4zCmmazmkSqOEkGr%2BoazheAUEANF6/rljgWAYEQFBUBYFI6HichKDQC6roSYAuGqGhaDLYgdogGINpicJmkgzgeruthBAAeQYWgAbq3gsFIoxxGh0h8HxBw8COHbEZRY5S02HrXVqDbKJiYh/o8LANqLFhAfKvgDGABRjTwTAw1BuNap6/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1ER3QuH0QxjBayx9GLHbIGWVAUnqDHv1B4E9m/HcxFoDWdwYVBvy8BgvCUdBv0nb8lAIX9miohDttqWcshcBh3E8do9FCdN5mGMXCkyARJj8P30gDhg5iGBIxbsJ2BF6CZ3byaPHdRuPxn6b3I70GYE9yYPbHTiOKl95Z2rWDY9DdTBcZplbqtIWr6sajhVHG/xv38SQ9mAZATmej0zD2CBmssawT1wQgSFOYqxb2Dx7voYhp%2BBLhFl4ProZbUgzyYLAEmJUghuBSQPSkRb5um2azEm/RODW0gqbOYEB8kMbvi4cbvjOSb/DbsXG94M3bau19qb1IEdU6uYUilhuhAO6l1F6RFYJsVu7dO7d17nsfuZheAZknu6dAehObCFEOIPmxDBZqA2qLUgYYSYpGphVKq61EbN1BqWaBeZUD6lQR3LuPc%2B5mAHkPeeCCXzdTXqArQW8d570oEw1avAqZmH8B6M43xJBLXGlIMwGgV7AnGg3DaQDbAgI3tIwaw0T5nyvgtK%2BN8VrAhYU3LaUiaYQIgEgeBD1YHeMXiAJ6L06DvU%2Bt9RGv1mDEChkDc6IMCDg0hhtWGEsEb1WRk7dGG0sbIBxtTcgz4Vr1SJiTKJZNNj1Upow2mTB6aM2ZqzRgeTiHczIdIChSgqEi0SOLIwKApY2CJnLA%2BitlacFVurb8pF1jehlJGBQYZai0Adt0ZwEBXBB09q7IuCwQ5FCyBs3ZYdtm%2By6LHBo6cDmnNTuc2Ymdi5RwLn0S5OcM5lCzqvFY5dea9XxDXBR9cAGbRbm3PhGDBHCOHv08e%2BA5zL1nqIh6y91zrwOpY4Ez90WYqxdi2%2BiiH4SA0HtQFJidp7XMQNXFOCjGsNceSreRwPrO0kEAA%3D%3D), without AVX, it's returned via a hidden pointer (in RDI) to the return-value object.  A caller assuming an AVX calling convention won't set RDI to a valid pointer, just pass it in YMM0.  (For passing by value, on the stack vs. in YMM0 will cause wrong data, but not a segfault directly.)

The `std::function` member functions were defined *without* AVX because you included C++ standard headers before that `pragma`.  But your later code will be using it with `__m256d`.